# Answers in mobile site scroll slightly

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web, mobile-chrome

In the last couple of days answers in the mobile (non-responsive) site have started scrolling slightly, by what appears to be 16 pixels. This affects the whole answer box down to the add comment button. When you scroll up a little white gap appears at the bottom, as shown:

[image: Normal view]

[image: Scrolled answer box]

It's a small change, but it does make it more difficult to scroll down the page because as you scroll down a page with many answers each answer claims one scroll gesture purely to move by 16 pixels without scrolling the page as a whole.

I'm using Chrome 87 on an Android 8 phone. 3.0 pixel density if that matters.

Comment: Why so many downvotes with no comments? I also noticed this issue within the last week or two. Chrome 87 on Android 10.

Comment: Same issue on Chrome 87, Android 8.0.

Comment: @Arthur It should no longer happen on the new responsive site. Click “full site” in the footer of any page. This bug will likely not be fixed, because the mobile site is largely obsolete and is being replaced by the responsive site.

Comment: @user289905 If it's obsolete, why are they still actively making changes? At any rate, here is a short video demonstration https://i.imgur.com/MHmPblS.gifv

Comment: @Arthur _Largely_ obsolete. I guess they’re only making critical changes, or changes that can easily be implemented.

Comment: Forgot that UI stuff should be reported here but here's a duplicate with more info ~ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403704/mobile-scrolling-bug. This can be fixed with one line of CSS change

Comment: @SebastianSimon I can attest that the problem still exists (Android Chrome).

Comment: @Spencer Did you click "full site" in the footer? It should not exist in the responsive version.

Comment: @Kodos The bug report is not for the responsive version. Many of us prefer the mobile version.

Comment: @curiousdannii sure, I was just responding to Spencer since they were responding to another commenter who specifically said to click the "full site" link. FWIW I did upvote this question and wish this would get resolved and even pondered why it was getting downvotes in the beginning.

Comment: @KodosJohnson I have to scroll to the bottom first before I can click "full site". This bug makes that difficult.

Comment: This may have been fixed. I'm not experiencing the issue anymore.

Comment: @texdr.aft: Still a problem on Android 11, Samsung Internet.